# Chrome OS: Crosh Window and Hostname

Tags: shell, keyboard-shortcuts, hostname, chrome-os

I have a couple of questions regarding Chrome OS:

- By default `Ctrl+Alt+T` opens a crosh window within the Chrome browser.  I have the Crosh Window extension, which I would like `Ctrl+Alt+T` bound to - how would I go about doing this?
- For various reasons, I need to have a hostname set both for the machine, and for DHCP requests.  I've read via a Google site that there is some form of option via Shill Manager - which I cannot find.  As such I'm at a loss as to how I can set a hostname.